# All devices can ping only themselves and the router (lan)

Tags: networking, lan, router

When i try to ping any devices in my lan network, i get this output :

```
ping 192.168.1.104     

PING 192.168.1.104 (192.168.1.104) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.108 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.108 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.108 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.108 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.108 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.108 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
```

The ping only suceed when pingin itself and the router :

itself -

```
ping 192.168.1.108                                                                                                                                            

PING 192.168.1.108 (192.168.1.108) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.108: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.029 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.108: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.042 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.108: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.065 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.108: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.063 ms
```

the router -

```
ping 192.168.1.1  

PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.92 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=3.17 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.05 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=1.38 ms
```

Tested with 3 devices, 2 linux and 1 android, and got the same output. ALl of them connected to the router via wifi. All host were up.

Output of some troubleshooting :

[ifconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eX4t.png)

[route -n, sudo iptables -L, arp -a, nmap -Sn 192.168.1.1/24](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7319g.png)

i tried `sudo ip route add 192.168.1.104/32 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0`  and `sudo ip route add 192.168.1.104 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0` but this is the output :

```
ping 192.168.1.104

PING 192.168.1.104 (192.168.1.104) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.1.104)
From 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.1.104)
From 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=4 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.1.104)
From 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=5 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.1.104)
From 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=6 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.1.104)
From 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=8 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.1.104)
From 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=11 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.1.104)
From 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=17 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.1.104)
From 192.168.1.108 icmp_seq=26 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.108 icmp_seq=27 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.108 icmp_seq=28 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.108 icmp_seq=29 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.108 icmp_seq=30 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.108 icmp_seq=31 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.108 icmp_seq=32 Destination Host Unreachable
```

I did try some other solutions, since its a common issue, but as none of them worked, i decided make another question about it.

Comment: From your "ifconfig" screenshot i see that it is a wireless network. It is an important information you missed to include - in case of such problems it is always important to describe the physical network topology. Some wireless routers block devices on wireless LAN from communicating with each other - they can only connect to the Internet. This is sometimes called a "guest network" functionality. Look in your router's manual and configuration panel if you can turn it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is in the same subnet, IP routing is completely irrelevant here. No routing is needed.

I noticed that it's a WiFi interface. Some WiFi routers have a setting "Isolate clients" or something similar. That could be the culprit here. Please have a look and disable it if it's on.

Other than that I can only imagine it to be 192.168.1.104's fault... maybe it has a wrong netmask? Can you double check that it's 255.255.255.0?